# wmctrl move window to workspace

Tags: wmctrl

I am trying to use `wmctrl` to move a window to a workspace.

By `wmctrl -l` window is

```
 0x03e00057  9 meer montazo - Google Search — Mozilla Firefox
```

Command and output is

```
 /usr/local/bin/wmctrl -v -i 0x03e00057 -t 3
 envir_utf8: 0
 No window was specified.
```

My understanding is that `-i` points to the hex id of the window (first field in the output list?), which in my simple mind i am doing here. Where am I astray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of `-t <DESK>`:

> Move a window that has been specified with the `-r` action to the desktop `<DESK>`.

Thus:

```
wmctrl -i -r 0x03e00057 -t 3
```

`-i` means that any argument that specifies a window is a window ID rather than a substring of the window title. It's a simple option, not followed by a window ID. It applies to the `<WIN>` argument of `-c`, `-r,` -R`, etc.